# widget behind Scaffold

Tags: flutter

I have a Widget behind the Scaffold that I made visible by setting Scaffold’s backgroundColor to transparent.

However, the Scaffold still absorbs the pointer event, but I want the background widget to consume the pointer event.

EDIT:

I cannot put the widget in the Scaffold since it is a platform widget (map view) and I have to make sure it’s the same instance across the whole app, otherwise funny things happen... also, page transitions should happen in front of the widget.

Comment: You could just put that Widget invisible into the Scaffold and make it visible with an event, instead of making the Scaffold transparent.

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: This map view widget you've got behind is static or you change it while usign the app?

Comment: It’s static and I created a stack in the MaterialApp builder to put the map behind the main widget. As I wrote in my answer, I solved the problem with a kind of “Hole” widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issues with two SingleChildRenderObjectWidgets.

One is called “Hole” and just a marker in the widget tree. The other one is called “Sieve” and checks in its hitTest if a Hole was hit below it.

If a Hole was hit, the hitTest is ignored.

Works perfectly!

Comment: Could you please share a minimal code example that illustrates your answer? I face a similar problem but I don't understand your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: true,
  child: Scaffold(
    ...
  ),
);
```

Comment: But that makes the whole Scaffold ignoring the pointer so that also the AppBar or body doesn’t get pointer events.

Comment: That's kind of a workaround. You can place some button which set the IgnorePointer state to True and the Scaffold trasnparent, so you can use the app Scaffold and anytime you want to ignore it, you tap that button.